# How do I throttle a Windows 7 remote desktop connection?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a remote desktop connection from one windows 7 machine to another windows 7 machine.  I would like to throttle the network connection to emulate the experience I would receive if the computers were not on the same local network.  In the past, I've used NetLimiter to throttle the network connection of specific applications on my computer.  This works if I rdp windows 7 into a windows xp machine.  However, no network traffic is shown when connecting windows 7 to windows 7.

How can I throttle a windows 7 rdp connection to another windows 7 computer?

Answer (score 2):

The only *quick* way I can think of is use a low end managed switch as (most of) these allow you to set bandwidth allocations on a per port basis. You can probably pick a second hand one up on eBay cheapish, if you don't already have a old one lying about.

If you are just running tests and have the hardware spare, you could also try using VmWare Workstation, this allows you to create teams of VMs and set the speed for the virtual network card.

Lastly, in Remote Desktop itself, you could always go to options and then the experience tab to test out on low bandwidth by disabling all the features, however this will only emulate a session optimised for low bandwidth links and obviously would actually be fast.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn down the settings in remote desktop. Open the expanded options, then select Experience. Then uncheck all but the last one. This ought to at least get you started. Combine that with the aformentioned bandwidth limitng programs and you should be set.

Comment: beat me! although it is worth pointing out that this will not actually be a low bandwidth session and will just copy the looks of a session that is optimised for low bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Clumsy for this matter. -> https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/

Note: Clumsy is a third party application and you should have the required permission to use it if this is part of your job. Just do your research and you'll fine when it comes to configuring it.

Comment: Are you associated with this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1189554)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).